# Помогите сгенерировать массив из 22-х элементов в интервале от -8 до 39

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
Var a:array [1..22] of integer;
      i:integer;
Begin
  for i:= -8 to 39 do
     begin
      randomize;
      a[i]:=random(39)-8;
      writeln('a(',i,')=',a[i]);
     end;
```

Пишет: Ошибка времени выполнения: Индекс находился вне границ массива.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `for i := 1 to 22 do`

Comment: Ошибка логична. "Ячейки" массива у вас имеют нумерацию от 1 до 22, а в цикле вы проходите от -8 до 39.

Comment: `for i:= -8 to 39 do` Объясните, что вы написали в этой строке и вы поймете свою ошибку!

Answer (score 0):

```
Var a:array [1..22] of integer;
      i:integer;
Begin
  for i := 1 to 22 do
     begin
      randomize;
      a[i]:=random(48)-8;
      writeln('a(',i,')=',a[i]);
     end;
```

Comment: Код сам по себе не является ответом на вопрос. Дополните, пожалуйста, ваш ответ экспертным комментарием.